# Creating list with range and change type of this list to string

Tags: python

```
number_count = int(input("Number count example (3 = 3 * 3): "))
range_list = [*range(number_count ** 2)]
y = 0
range_list[:] = 'X'
for x in range_list:
    y += 1
    print(range_list[x], end=' ')
    if y == number_count:
        print('\n')
        y = 0
```

I tried this but 'range_list[:] = "X"' give me error. My desire is basic i want to change all elements in list to 'X' or 'O'.

Comment: `['X' for _ in range(number_count ** 2)]`…?

Comment: `list('X' * number_count ** 2)`…?

Comment: `range_list[:] = ['X' * len(range_list)]`...?